# Add data to array by row

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to add data to an array by row (and by sheet).  However, none of the approaches I have tried below work.  I am sure there is a very simple answer, but it escapes me and I cannot locate an answer by searching the internet.  Thank you for any advice.

```
I <- 4 # rows
J <- 2 # columns
K <- 3 # sheets

my.data <- array( 0 , c(I,J,K))

sheet1 <- c(2,5)
sheet2 <- c(7,1)
sheet3 <- c(4,4)

# desired result
#
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    5
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    2    5
# [4,]    2    5
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    7    1
# [2,]    7    1
# [3,]    7    1
# [4,]    7    1
# 
# , , 3
# 
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    4    4
# [2,]    4    4
# [3,]    4    4
# [4,]    4    4
```

None of these work:

```
my.data <- array( 0 , c(I,J,K)) ; my.data[1:I,    , 1] <- sheet1 ; my.data
my.data <- array( 0 , c(I,J,K)) ; my.data[,    1:J, 1] <- sheet1 ; my.data
my.data <- array( 0 , c(I,J,K)) ; aperm(my.data[1:I,,1], perm=sheet1)  ; my.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each value repeated 4 times so use `rep()` and `[<-`

```
 my.data[ , , 1:3] <- rep( c(sheet1,sheet2, sheet3), each=4) 
> my.data
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    5
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    2    5
[4,]    2    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    1
[2,]    7    1
[3,]    7    1
[4,]    7    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4
[3,]    4    4
[4,]    4    4
```

Loops? We don't need no steenking loops!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not dead set on creating `my.data` via replacement, you can try:

```
sheets <- list(sheet1, sheet2, sheet3)
vapply(sheets, rep, matrix(numeric(), ncol=J, nrow=I), each=I)
```

Otherwise:

```
my.data <- array( 0 , c(J,I,K))
my.data[, , 1] <- sheet1
my.data[, , 2] <- sheet2
my.data[, , 3] <- sheet3
aperm(my.data, c(2, 1, 3))
```

Notice how I switched `J` and `I` from what you had.  You need to do this because vector recycling is done on a column basis (i.e. fill a column, and then recycle).  By creating the array with dimensions 1 and 2 transposed, you can allow your pairs of values to recycle gracefully (i.e. first value to first row, second to second).

When you are done, you can then permute the 1st and 2nd dims with `aperm` as you had tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way, but it used nested `for-loops`:

```
I <- 4 # rows
J <- 2 # columns
K <- 3 # sheets

my.data <- array( 0 , c(I,J,K))

sheet1 <- c(2,5)
sheet2 <- c(7,1)
sheet3 <- c(4,4)

for(i in 1:I) { 
     for(j in 1:J) { 
          for(k in 1:K)  { 

              if (k == 1) (my.data[i,j,k] = sheet1[j]) 
              if (k == 2) (my.data[i,j,k] = sheet2[j])
              if (k == 3) (my.data[i,j,k] = sheet3[j])

                         }
                   }
              }

my.data

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    5
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    2    5
[4,]    2    5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    1
[2,]    7    1
[3,]    7    1
[4,]    7    1

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4
[3,]    4    4
[4,]    4    4
```